# SQL Show All Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting 331 result rows when I want to get all 595 from the inner most query.  The reason it eliminates 264 rows (595-331=264) is that those 264 rows do not meet all of the crieria in STEP #2.  The 331 rows that do pass the criteria get a '>>>' in the OK column.  So, I want to show the most recent date for the 331 rows, plus I want to show the 'cid' and NULL values for the other 264 that do not pass the criteria in STEP #2.

As a C# programmer, I can think of many ways to do this.  But, what is the best way to do this in SQL?

```
/* STEP #4: ORDER RESULTS*/ /* SEE LINE 43 FOR ALL EVENTS */
SELECT          cid
, edate, OK
, (SELECT CASE WHEN OK = '>>>'
THEN DATEDIFF(day, edate, ChartResp.TxPlanDueDate(t2.cid))
ELSE NULL
END
) AS 'DaysBtwnDueDateAndLDOSPrimClin'
, eser, eatt, erecip, Age, ccm, estaff
FROM            (
/* STEP #3: SELECT MOST RECENT EVENT FROM STEP 2 FOR EACH CLIENT*/
SELECT          *
FROM            (
/* STEP #2: SELECT EVENTS THAT PASS FILTER CRITERIA FOR THOSE CLIENTS*/
SELECT          --cid, edate, eser, eatt, erecip, DATEDIFF    (Year, cbd, GetDate()) AS 'Age', ccm, estaff, 
(SELECT CASE WHEN 
(eatt IN (1,2)
AND edate > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
AND eser NOT IN (100,115,142)
AND erecip NOT IN ('2','7')
AND (( (erecip = '3') AND (DATEDIFF(Year, cbd, GetDate())<10) ) OR (erecip     <> '3') )
AND ccm = estaff)
THEN '>>>'
ELSE ''
END
) AS 'OK'
,cid, edate, eser, eatt, erecip, DATEDIFF(Year, cbd, GetDate()) AS 'Age',     ccm, estaff
,rownumber() OVER (PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY edate DESC) rn                 
FROM events INNER JOIN client ON ecaseno = cid
LEFT OUTER JOIN doc ON doc.docdbid = client.cid
WHERE client.cid IN (
/* STEP #1: SELECT CLIENTS THAT ARE IN ORIGINAL OVERDUE TX PLAN REPORT */    SELECT client.cid
FROM client LEFT OUTER JOIN admission ON client.cid = admission.cid
WHERE ((client.ctype = 'AC') AND (admission.alapdt IS NULL))
GROUP BY client.cid
HAVING ((ChartResp.TxPlanDueDate(client.cid) < DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE())) 
AND (dbo.FFT(client.cid) IS NULL) 
AND (dbo.IsHousingOnly(client.cid) IS NULL) 
AND (DATEDIFF(day, ChartResp.TxPlanDueDate(client.cid),DATEADD(day, - 1,     GETDATE())) > 0))
/* STEP #1 END */
)
AND eser BETWEEN 11 AND 1000
AND ccm = estaff
AND eatt IN (1,2)
AND edate > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
AND eser NOT IN (100,115,142)
AND erecip NOT IN ('2','7')
AND (( (erecip = '3') AND (DATEDIFF(Year, cbd, GetDate())<10) ) OR (erecip     <> '3') )
GROUP BY cid, edate, eser, eatt, erecip, cbd, ccm, estaff
/* STEP #2 END */
) t1
WHERE rn = 1-- COMMENT THIS OUT TO SEE ALL EVENTS
/* STEP #3 END */
) t2
ORDER BY cid, edate DESC
```

Comment: With a union all query.

Comment: Awsome Dan! You rock.  So, what I did was double my query in step #2 and combined those two with a UNION ALL.  That gives me a result of 908 rows and now I have to figure out how to take only the most recent date from that 908 for each cid.

Comment: So my first idea to reduce the 908 only got it down to 840: I used a MAX(edate) in step #3 select.  I will keep trying other stuff.  A bit sloppy, I know, but there is no need to optimize this query, our system is not over burdened and anything I throw at it runs fast.

Comment: Here is a sample result.  Where cid is b1 and b2 the rows repeat – instead, I need to take the most recent date.  Any suggestions?  Thank You!

cid edate OK DaysBtwnDueDateAndLDOSPrimClin eser eatt erecip Age ccm estaff
a1 11/6/2013  NULL 10 2 7 31 1289 2407
a2 11/1/2013  NULL -6 NULL NULL 46 2563 NULL
a3 11/1/2013  NULL -6 NULL NULL 26 2539 NULL
b1 11/5/2013  NULL 10 2 7 61 1689 641
b1 7/12/2013 >>> -90 190 1 1 61 1689 1689
b2 11/5/2013  NULL 102 6 9 27 9567 9567
b2 10/29/2013 >>> -55 110 1 1 27 9567 9567
a4 10/31/2013 >>> -13 110 2 1 38 2713 2713
a5 11/6/2013  NULL 200 1 3 15 9581 9581

Comment: sorry, how do I post it with tab deliminated columns?

Comment: cid edate OK Days eser eatt erecip Age ccm estaff
a1 11/6/2013  NULL 10 2 7 31 1289 2407
a2 11/1/2013  NULL -6 NULL NULL 46 2563 NULL
a3 11/1/2013  NULL -6 NULL NULL 26 2539 NULL
b1 11/5/2013  NULL 10 2 7 61 1689 641
b1 7/12/2013 >>> -90 190 1 1 61 1689 1689
b2 11/5/2013  NULL 102 6 9 27 9567 9567
b2 10/29/2013 >>> -55 110 1 1 27 9567 9567
a4 10/31/2013 >>> -13 110 2 1 38 2713 2713
a5 11/6/2013  NULL 200 1 3 15 9581 9581

Comment: BINGO!!!  So, a prior StackFlow guru (person with a generous sole) showed me how to use OVER PARTITION BY. Now I simply use that twice, or actually thrice -- twice in step #2 and one more time in step #3 -- and I am down to only the most recdent qualifying row for each cid.  Awsome, Dan!  Thank you for getting me started.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CTE to prepare your required data set and then use a query to join back to your CTE to get the required outpu.